# How do I get the Current Working Directory for Grails/Tomcat Webapp?

Tags: tomcat, grails, working-directory

I wrote a Grails webapp for Tomcat that opens and reads from a Berkeley DB on ./data/transactions/foobar.

This code runs fine in my Eclipse environmet.

But when I move it to the server, it spits out this exception.  I am not sure where the current working directory when I deploy the Grails in a WAR file as a webapps web application on the Server.

```
com.sleepycat.je.EnvironmentNotFoundException: (JE 4.1.10) ./data/transactions/Foobar
Home directory: ./data/transactions/Foobar ENV_NOT_FOUND: 
EnvironmentConfig.setAllowCreate is false so environment creation is not permitted, but there are no log files in the environment directory. Environment is invalid and must be closed.
```

My Tomcat install directory on the Linux server is /usr/share/tomcat6.  The webapps root dir is /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps.  We WAR directory is in installed in a subdirectory named "bridge."  The WAR path to my Grails app is in /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/bridge

I tried putting the ./data/transaction/Foobar in both /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps and /usr/share/tomcat6/webapps/bridge, with no luck.

I also tried putting ./data/transaction/Foobar into /usr/share/tomcat6 install base directory, also with no luck.

The following are the errors I see from the Tomcat server:

```
Error 500: Executing action [index] of controller[com.ecmhp.ecmdatabridge.generators.GenerateEmiDigestsController] 
caused exception: (JE 4.1.10) ./data/transactions/Foobar 
    Home directory: ./data/transactions/Foobar ENV_NOT_FOUND: 
    EnvironmentConfig.setAllowCreate is false so environment creation is not permitted, but there are no log files in the environment directory. Environment is invalid and must be closed.
```

Servlet: grails

URI: /bridge/grails/generateEmiDigests/index.dispatch

```
Exception Message: (JE 4.1.10) ./data/transactions/Foobar 
Home directory: ./data/transactions/Foobar ENV_NOT_FOUND: 
EnvironmentConfig.setAllowCreate is false so environment creation is not permitted, but there are no log files in the environment directory. Environment is invalid and must be closed. 

Caused by: (JE 4.1.10) ./data/transactions/Foobar 
    Home directory: ./data/transactions/Foobar ENV_NOT_FOUND: 
    EnvironmentConfig.setAllowCreate is false so environment creation is not permitted, but there are no log files in the environment directory. Environment is invalid and must be closed.
```

Any idea how I can set the current working directory for my Tomcat WAR so that it finds the Berkeley DB ./data/transaction files?  Or any idea I can find out what the current working directory is my Grails app is launched?

Answer (score 8):

If you can get a hold of the 'grailsApplication' bean, which is or can be autoinjected in different parts of the Grails framework you can try:

```
grailsApplication.mainContext.servletContext.getRealPath('/data/transactions/foobar')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you install the Console plugin for grails, you can just run

```
new File( 'test.html' ).absolutePath
```

For our app, this returns /data/opt/tomcat/5.5/, so I imagine that you need to put your directory inside usr/share/tomcat6/data/transactions